# Search result issue with Search API Module in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm working with `Drupal-7`; where i have installed so many different modules in it. one of them modules is `"Search API"`.

The problem what i'm facing is Result of searched keyword. whenever i use to search for a particular keyword it working for the Exact match with that key word.

**For example :**  `keyword = "Drupal" ;` 
then result only retrieved if this exact word will match with the content of database. but i would like to get result which are having any of these characters.

**For example :** `keyword = "Dru" ;` 
then also all the result will retrieved which is having only word `"Dru"` as well as `"Drupal"`  & etc..

In short now Query is working with `"="` operator but i would like to make it with `"LIKE"` operator.

**What should i do in which page to get resolve this..?**

I have tried to many things but not get success..Please help me out.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Unfortunately, this is too old to migrate to Drupal Answers.

Comment: I keep forgetting about that limit. `:)` Thank you the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal core does not allow partial search string search. Below are your options if you want partial string search in your results.

1) Use Apache solr server.

2) http://drupal.org/project/porterstemmer is another one

3) use google custom site search instead . http://drupal.org/project/google_cse

Hope this helps.

Cheers,
Vishal